# IIS7.5 running both 32bit and 64bit websites

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

Can someone tell me if its possible to run both a 64bit compiled web site and a 32bit compiled website on the same IIS7.5 machine.  The core OS would be Windows 2008 R2 64bit.  I looked around and can only find how to switch the appPools to 32 or 64.  But the question I want answered is can you have one appPool 32bit and another 64bit?  If you can link to some articles that would certainly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's no problem to have differing "bitness" on different application pools.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2007/11/03/iis7-running-32-bit-and-64-bit-asp-net-versions-at-the-same-time-on-different-worker-processes.aspx

-Oisin